# Ruby ActiveRecord association generates error when accessing child

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby, activerecord

**Introduction**: I'm creating a standalone (non-Rails) application that uses ActiveRecord and ActiveRecord SQL Server Adapter to access a database for a commercial application.  I'm unable to change the database schema or the database server, as much as I'd like to.  I've tried to change the names below to protect the guilty.

**The base model class:**

```
class AppRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :parent_init
  attr_reader :_downcase_field_values
  attr_accessor :downcase_field_values

  self.primary_key = 'IRN'

  def parent_init
    set_downcase_field_values
  end

  def set_downcase_field_values
    @downcase_field_values ||= []
    @_downcase_field_values = self.attributes.keys.select { |att| att if (att.match(/IRN/) || att == "Id") }
    downcase_fields! self
  end

  def self.table_name
    "app.#{self}"
  end

  def to_h
    self.attributes.to_options
  end
end
```

**The model classes:**

```
class ReportIndex < AppRecord
  after_find :init

  has_many :ReportIndexParameters, class_name: "ReportIndexParameters", foreign_key: "ReportIndexIRN", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ReportProperties, class_name: "ReportProperties", foreign_key: "ReportIndexIRN", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ReportLayouts, class_name: "ReportLayouts", foreign_key: "ReportIndexIRN", dependent: :destroy

  has_many :ReportIndexSeries, class_name: "ReportIndexSeries", foreign_key: "ReportIndexesIRN", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ReportUserDefinedViews, class_name: "ReportUserDefinedViews", foreign_key: "BaseClassID", primary_key: "ClassId"

  def init
    self.downcase_field_values = %w(BaseClassID)
  end
end

class ReportProperties < AppRecord
  belongs_to :ReportIndex
  after_find :init
  has_many :ReportPropertySeriesFilters, class_name: "ReportPropertySeriesFilters", foreign_key: "ReportPropertiesIRN", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ReportPropertyParameters, class_name: "ReportPropertyParameters", foreign_key: "ReportPropertiesIRN", dependent: :destroy
  def init
    self.downcase_field_values = %w(ClassID)
  end
end
```

**The ActiveRecord query:**

`pp ReportIndex.includes(:ReportProperties).find_by(ReportName: report_name)`

**The error:**

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb:63:in `block in associated_records_by_owner': undefined method `association' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/core.rb:367:in `init_with'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:69:in `instantiate'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/querying.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in find_by_sql'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/result.rb:55:in `block in each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/result.rb:55:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/result.rb:55:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/querying.rb:50:in `map'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/querying.rb:50:in `block in find_by_sql'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/querying.rb:49:in `find_by_sql'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:678:in `exec_queries'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:546:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb:122:in `block in load_records'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb:121:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb:121:in `each_slice'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb:121:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb:121:in `flat_map'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb:121:in `load_records'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb:61:in `associated_records_by_owner'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/collection_association.rb:8:in `preload'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/associations/preloader/association.rb:19:in `run'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:151:in `block (2 levels) in preloaders_for_one'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:149:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:149:in `map'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:149:in `block in preloaders_for_one'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:148:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:148:in `flat_map'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:148:in `preloaders_for_one'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:115:in `preloaders_on'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:102:in `block in preload'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:101:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:101:in `flat_map'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb:101:in `preload'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:686:in `block in exec_queries'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:684:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:684:in `exec_queries'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:546:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:255:in `records'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:508:in `find_take'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:100:in `take'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.6/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:78:in `find_by'
    from /src/artest.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

**However, the SQL generated by ActiveRecord seems to be correct:**

```
D, [2018-06-27T17:42:49.256232 #1] DEBUG -- :   SQL (33.3ms)  USE [APP]
D, [2018-06-27T17:42:50.017505 #1] DEBUG -- :   ReportIndex Load (40.5ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [app].[ReportIndex].* FROM [app].[ReportIndex] WHERE [app].[ReportIndex].[ReportName] = @0  ORDER BY [app].[ReportIndex].[IRN] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @1 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 nvarchar(80), @1 int', @0 = N'Master Condemnation', @1 = 1  [["ReportName", nil], ["LIMIT", nil]]
D, [2018-06-27T17:42:51.043389 #1] DEBUG -- :   ReportProperties Load (133.9ms)  SELECT [app].[ReportProperties].* FROM [app].[ReportProperties] WHERE [app].[ReportProperties].[ReportIndexIRN] = '3cad6165-221e-4607-b5ad-01bc32f29157'
```

I suspect that these irregularities stem from something I've managed to get wrong architecturally.  The existing model code works fine for `DELETE` and `UPDATE` operations but not for `SELECT`s.  I welcome the hive mind to give me its two cents.

Comment: These mixed case symbol names are ver unconventional. I would certainly try to avoid using them.

Comment: You know that the sql server adapter can downcase the fields for you using `lowercase_schema_reflection`

Comment: I'll look into `lowercase_schema_reflection`.  I did not know about that.

Comment: David - I'd love to avoid using unconventional symbol names.  If you can tell me how I can interface with this database without changing the schema while using ActiveRecord conventions, I'm all ears.

Comment: @engineersmnky - I can't tell that `lowercase_schema_reflection` is doing anything different.  It certainly doesn't change the case of the GUIDs (which I need to be lowercase for the XML file that I'm generating), and it doesn't seem to help with the case of the column names, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What I learned:**

- It is generally a bad idea to subclass `ActiveRecord::Base` unless you really know what you're doing, and I didn't.  The best way to share code among classes in your model is to use a module.  Subclassing `ActiveRecord::Base` can have unintended side effects, and unless I am very mistaken, it does not enable you to share callback code, anyway.
- As far as I can tell, these options have no effect with version 5.1.6 of the activerecord-sqlserver-adapter gem, contrary to the docs:
  `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLServerAdapter.lowercase_schema_reflection = true`
  `ActiveRecord::Base.table_name_prefix = prefix`

  I resolved both of these by setting self.table_name in the module's `included` block. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I could not get either of these options to work, and in fact couldn't tell a difference in the generated SQL.  As a result, I still have to deal with CamelCase column names.
- MSSQL's `uniqueidentifier` columns are case insensitive.  The app I'm writing this code for uses the lowercase variant with every GUID, so I was under the impression that I had to mimic this behavior, but the database does
  n't care.  I spent much time trying to get `ActiveRecord` to automatically `downcase` these fields, and I kind of got it to work, but it didn't have good results.  See the next item.
- If you try to alter the value of your primary key through `after_init`, `after_find`, etc., it will break associations.  In my case, I was trying
  to change the primary key from a `uniqueidentifier` datatype, to a string
  version with `downcase`d hex values.  This is what produced the original
  error that caused me to create this post.

**The code:**

> *Note:* The `ActiveSupport::Inflector` section is needed to make sure things that don't need to be pluralized are not pluralized.  For more information see the `ActiveSupport::Inflector` docs.

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'index', 'index'
  inflect.irregular 'layoutml', 'layoutml'
  inflect.acronym 'ML'
end

module AppRecord
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    self.primary_key = 'IRN'
    self.table_name = "app.#{self.to_s.pluralize}"
  end

  def to_h
    self.attributes.to_options
  end
end

class ReportIndex < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AppRecord
  has_many :report_index_parameters, foreign_key: "ReportIndexIRN", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :report_properties, foreign_key: "ReportIndexIRN", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :report_layouts, foreign_key: "ReportIndexIRN", dependent: :destroy

  has_many :report_index_series, foreign_key: "ReportIndexesIRN", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :report_user_defined_views, foreign_key: "ClassId", primary_key: "BaseClassID"

  has_many :report_index_param_series_filters, through: :report_index_series
  has_many :report_property_series_filters, through: :report_index_series
  has_many :report_layout_images, through: :report_layouts
  has_many :report_layout_ml, through: :report_layouts
  has_many :report_property_parameters, through: :report_properties
end

class ReportProperty < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AppRecord
  has_many :report_property_series_filters, foreign_key: "ReportPropertiesIRN", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :report_property_parameters, foreign_key: "ReportPropertiesIRN", dependent: :destroy
end
```

**Unresolved questions:**

- Is there a way to change the scheme `ActiveRecord` uses to guess foreign keys?  The foreign keys in this app do not match the `"#{class.to_s.underscore}_id"` convention, but rather the `"#{class.to_s}IRN"` convention.  How do I DRY my code out and keep from naming every regular foreign key in my associations?
- Is there a way to declare that ALL of my has_many associations should have `dependent: :destroy` set?  Again, this would help me DRY out my code.

Thanks to everyone who has commented so far.